# Docker on mac on VMWare

Tags: mac-osx, virtual-machines, docker

I am running mac VMs managed by vmware (locally in our DC), using them as agents for our CI workflow.

My intentions were to install docker on these machines, in order to convert some of my build steps to run in containers. Alas, when trying to install docker I received the following error - https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/troubleshoot/#incompatible-cpu-detected

Running the command suggested by the documentation (`sysctl kern.hv_support`) returns the output `kern.hv_support: 0`.

Is there anyway to enable hv_support for mac vms?

I realize there might be a lot of data missing from this question, let me know if there are any details I can supply to clarify my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under VMWare fusion 8.5 you need to enable hypervisor support (it's not on by default). Go to Virtual Machine / Settings and click on the "Processors and Memory" icon. Under "Advanced Options" you can select the checkbox for "enable hypervisor applications in this virtual machine".

You may need to reboot the VM, after doing this re-run sysctl kern.hv_support, you should see hypervisor support is enabled.

I am able to fire up docker on a MacOS Sierra VM under VMware fusion, so it does work...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sadly this is a hardware issues with the hosts running our VMs, so there is no real way around this error until we switch them.